# Present continuous form for a polite question?

Tags: tenses, politeness, progressive-aspect

Should we use use the present continuous form "***would you mind if***" to ask a polite question?

Comment: The present continuous form of _would you mind if_ would be _would you be minding if_. If that is what you meant, you can't.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should not.  It is ungrammatical to say:

> *Would you mind if I am sleeping here?

The sequence of tenses needs to be more like either this:

> Would you mind if I slept here?

or even

> Would you mind if I sleep here?

Although some might take exception with one or the other of that pair, both are heard in the wild.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence as such is grammatically incorrect. You could have used

> Would you mind if I sleep here?

if you are inclined to using a present continuous form.

Though you are correct in using "*would you mind*" here, I'd suggest you use, "*Do you mind*" for questions with similar structure.

Comment: If the answer really helps you, an upvote would surely please me. :)